# Using arrows-keys to navigate

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am wondering if there was a possibility to navigate with arrow keys through a table I created with JS(using jQuery)? I mean jumping from cell to cell...The script is for Greasemonkey.

The alert, however, works. I just got no idea how to make it well-functioning.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed " );
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       alert( "up pressed " );
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       alert( "right pressed " );
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       alert( "down pressed " );
       return false;
    }
});
;
```

Any hint or whatever is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Faili

**Update**

It seems like I explained myself wrong. Give me another try:
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s3YDC/)

This one may give you an idea of what I wanted. After selecting one input-field a navigation with arrow keys is possible.
My problem is that I just can't realise it via GM and jQuery. Any idea?

Thanks again for your time and effort.

**Finally** it was like:

```
function myTest_analysis1(e,leftkey,up,right,down){
    myTest(e,'','','field_analysis2','field_communication1')

function myTest(e,leftkey,up,right,down)
{
  if (!e) e=window.event;
  var selectArrowKey;
  switch(e.keyCode)
  {
  case 37:
    // Key left.
    selectArrowKey = leftkey;
    break;
  case 38:
    // Key up.
    selectArrowKey = up;
    break;
  case 39:
    // Key right.
    selectArrowKey = right;
    break;
  case 40:
    // Key down.
    selectArrowKey = down;
    break;
  }
  if (!selectArrowKey) return;  
  var controls = window.document.getElementById(selectArrowKey);
  if (!controls) return;
  controls.focus();
}
}
 $('#field_analysis1').keydown (myTest_analysis1);
```

That's how it worked out for me. I bet there is a smarter solution, but I couldn't figure it out right now.

Thank you sooo much for your time and effort.

Comment: explain what do you mean with `navigate through a table`..

Comment: I got a table with lots of rows and cells. E.g. by pressing the left-arrow-key the focus should change from the actual cell to the neighbour cell on the left.

Comment: What's the purpose of such navigation, are there activatable links in the cells or something? Cells themselves are not naturally focus-taking elements. You can trick them into being focusable by writing a `tabIndex` property, and style them with a `:focus` rule, but what interaction is possible on a focused cell?

Comment: I'll get back to you asap. It's too warm in the room I'm working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to focus the various cells, I will put an example together using .focus()

Here is the example.

Please bear in mind that...

a) There is nothing in this example to stop you from going out of bounds, you would need to restrict the values of currentRow and currentCell to the number of cells and prevent them from going below 0.

b) At the moment, there is no code to remove the green text, which is what I've used to show the current focus. This means a green trail is left behind.

You could solve both of the above fairly easily, but they would make the example more complicated...

```
    var currentRow = 0;
    var currentCell = 0;

    function ChangeCurrentCell() {
        var tableRow = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[currentRow];
        var tableCell = tableRow.childNodes[currentCell];
        tableCell.focus();
        tableCell.style.color = "Green";
    }
    ChangeCurrentCell();

    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
           currentCell--;
           ChangeCurrentCell();
           return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
           currentRow--;
           ChangeCurrentCell();
           return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
           currentCell++;
           ChangeCurrentCell();
           return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
           currentRow++;
           ChangeCurrentCell();
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that I explained myself very well. Anyway, thank you for some hints :-)

Comment: I mark this as solved because it's understandable and may help others.

Comment: @sohnee. i need a favor lets say if all td's have input textbox how to move between them like this? thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a version that allows for the following

1. constrains at start and end of the table (first and last cell of the table)
2. wraps at the end of each row and moves to the next
3. scrolls the current cell into view if there is scrolling required to see it
4. supports mouse-click to select a cell

**Demo at** : https://jsfiddle.net/BdVB9/

---

with an html structure like

```
<table id="navigate">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and javascript

```
var active = 0;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    reCalculate(e);
    rePosition();
    return false;
});
    
$('td').click(function(){
   active = $(this).closest('table').find('td').index(this);
   rePosition();
});


function reCalculate(e){
    var rows = $('#navigate tr').length;
    var columns = $('#navigate tr:eq(0) td').length;
    //alert(columns + 'x' + rows);
    
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
        active = (active>0)?active-1:active;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
        active = (active-columns>=0)?active-columns:active;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
       active = (active<(columns*rows)-1)?active+1:active;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
        active = (active+columns<=(rows*columns)-1)?active+columns:active;
    }
}

function rePosition(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#navigate tr td').eq(active).addClass('active');
    scrollInView();
}

function scrollInView(){
    var target = $('#navigate tr td:eq('+active+')');
    if (target.length)
    {
        var top = target.offset().top;
        
        $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: top-100}, 400);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

here is my version...

## [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ZkaSu/)

```
var active;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    active = $('td.active').removeClass('active');
    var x = active.index();
    var y = active.closest('tr').index();
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       x--;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        y--;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
        x++
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        y++
    }
    active = $('tr').eq(y).find('td').eq(x).addClass('active');
});​
```

Comment: 2 things; you need to `return false;` from the event to prevent the page from scrolling if it has scrollbars and second, you need to scroll the active td into view if it's not currently visible on the screen. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkaSu/1/)

Comment: good work reigel. i need a favor lets say if all td's have input textbox how to move between them like this? thanks.