# Keyboard arrow navigation through images in the 4 directions

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, arrows

I've been working on a project for uni, and while I'm familiar with HTML and CSS, my knowledge with js is very vague.

I'm trying right now to make some kind of gallery where you can navigate with keyboard arrows through images that sometimes branches in any of the 4 directions, think of it as a 'Choose Your Own Adventure' book, but I'm kind of stuck.

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8DIh.png), where every frame covers the whole screen and you navigate through it like the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510565/using-arrows-keys-to-navigate-and-select-text-in-input-box):  but in any direction as long as there is another frame there.

Comment: you can use two-dimensional array, and fill it with pass/not pass values. Check possible ways when you step at point.

Comment: my knowledge with js is rather limited, if you had an example or something where this is used it would help me a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See comments and links below!

It's ugly but worked solution, if you are novice, it may help you in your learning:

```
var coord = function (name, isPass,x,y) {
    return {
        name: name,
        pass: isPass | false,
        x:x,
        y:y
    }
}
var map = [
    [
        new coord("x:0,y:0", true,0,0),
        new coord("x:1,y:0", true,1,0)
    ],
    [
        new coord("x:0,y:1", false,0,1),
        new coord("x:1,y:1", true,1,1)
    ],
]
const notPossibleCoord = new coord("", false, -1, -1);
var currentPosition = new coord("", false, -1, -1);
function tryMove(direction) {    
    var nextDirection;
    try {
        switch (direction) {
            case "top": nextDirection = map[currentPosition.x][currentPosition.y + 1]; break;
            case "bottom": nextDirection = map[currentPosition.x][currentPosition.y - 1]; break;
            case "left": nextDirection = map[currentPosition.x - 1][currentPosition.y]; break;
            case "right": nextDirection = map[currentPosition.x + 1][currentPosition.y + 1]; break;
            default:
                return notPossibleCoord
        }
        if (nextDirection.pass)
            return nextDirection;
        else
            return notPossibleCoord;
    } catch (e) {
        //index out of range, it's your edge
        return notPossibleCoord;
    }
}

function onArrowPress() {
    var prevPosition = currentPosition;
    currentPosition = tryMove("top");
    if (currentPosition == notPossibleCoord)
        return; //do nothing if movement not possible

    //do what you need to do
}
```

**Some comments:**

1. we declare function-object which subscribe coord item
2. create your map (in your case map will be created by 'images-nodes')
3. create const `not possible` **(be care! it's need ES6(ES2015 may be)**, so, instead of `const` you can use just `var`;
4. declare function `tryMove` - it's your main function for movements
5. set on `document.keyPress` or something event our function `onArrowPress`, check is it 'arrow' or not, and do your logic

---

What you need to learn for understand that's all:

1. [Using an Object Constructor](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)
2. [JavaScript Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
3. [JavaScript Switch Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)
4. [JavaScript Errors](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)
5. [`onkeypress` Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)
6. [JavaScript HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)