# Move with arrow keys in a contenteditable table

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

**How to move with <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> keyboard arrows in the cells of a `<table>` which is `contenteditable`?**

Is this possible with CSS? Does one need Javascript for this?

```html
<table>
  <tr><td contenteditable>A1</td><td contenteditable>A2</td><td contenteditable>A3</td><td contenteditable>A4</td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable>A1</td><td contenteditable>A2</td><td contenteditable>A3</td><td contenteditable>A4</td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable>A1</td><td contenteditable>A2</td><td contenteditable>A3</td><td contenteditable>A4</td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable>A1</td><td contenteditable>A2</td><td contenteditable>A3</td><td contenteditable>A4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: See this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245398/using-arrows-keys-to-navigate and this; http://www.coderanch.com/t/120302/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Arrow-Key-Move-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT last post would not work on contenteditable table.

This triggers focus and moves left,right,up & down.

Here's a link to the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ytfLxxes/1/

```
var active = 0;


$(document).keydown(function(e){
    reCalculate(e);
    rePosition();
    return false;
});

$('td').click(function(){
   active = $(this).closest('table').find('td').index(this);
   rePosition();
});


function reCalculate(e){
    var rows = $('#navigate tr').length;
    var columns = $('#navigate tr:eq(0) td').length;
    //alert(columns + 'x' + rows);

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left or wrap
        active = (active>0)?active-1:active;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // move up
        active = (active-columns>=0)?active-columns:active;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { // move right or wrap
       active = (active<(columns*rows)-1)?active+1:active;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // move down
        active = (active+columns<=(rows*columns)-1)?active+columns:active;
    }
}

function rePosition(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#navigate tr td').eq(active).addClass('active').trigger( "focus" );
    scrollInView();
}

function scrollInView(){
    var target = $('#navigate tr td:eq('+active+')');
    if (target.length)
    {
        var top = target.offset().top;

        $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: top-100}, 400);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you turn it into a jsfiddle or runnable code snippet?

Comment: I see the problem now! This won't work on a content editable table because the it'll just move along the text that you are editing rather than change position on the table.

Comment: @Basj there you go that should help :P

Answer (score -1):

Do you need javascript for this, you can use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) for that and check if the key pressed was arrow key.

The [keyup event](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) is very useful in this situation.

Then, after arrow key was pressed, you must navigate from js and put the cursor in the correct `td` with conteneditable.

I hope will be useful, best regards. Leo